# What CPU architecture can I compile for AWS Fargate and Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-fargate, avx2

When compiling software to be executed in AWS Fargate or Lambda, what is the maximum assumption I can make about its architecture? Meaning, can I compile binaries with `-march=skylake` for example?

The following article from AWS states that Lambda functions can use AVX2:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-faster-aws-lambda-functions-with-avx2/

Does this mean I should limit my compilation flags to `-mavx2`? Is this valid to Fargate as well?

I couldn't find any documentation about this.